# Save the Required items from one Dict to another Dict

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a Dict 'sample', And I want to save the required items from 'sample' to another Dict sample1.

my Dict is like,

```
sample=[{
        'Name':'n1',
         'SNo':1,
         'Status':{
                   'state':'None',
                    'Health':'Ok'
                  },
          'Contact':'No'
          'Address':'No' 

        },
         {
        'Name':'n2',
         'SNo':2,
         'Status':{
                   'state':'Present',
                    'Health':'Ok'
                  },
          'Contact':'Yes'
          'Address':'Not Provided'

        },
        {
        'Name':'n3',
         'SNo':3,
         'Status':{
                   'state':'None',
                    'Health':'Ok'
                  },
          'Contact':'No'
          'Address':'Provided' 

        }]
```

from the above Dict (sample), I want to save the items ('Name','SNo','Status') into another Dict (sample1).

And the Expected result should be,

```
sample1={
'Details':{
        'Name':'n1',
         'SNo':1,
         'Status':{
                   'state':'None',
                    'Health':'Ok'
                  }
         },
         {
        'Name':'n2',
         'SNo':2,
         'Status':{
                   'state':'Present',
                    'Health':'Ok'
                  }
        },
        {
        'Name':'n3',
         'SNo':3,
         'Status':{
                   'state':'None',
                    'Health':'Ok'
                  }
        } 
         }
```

And I tried,

```
Sample1={}
res={}
for data in sample:
     if data.has_key('Name') and data.has_key('SNo') and data.has_key('Status'):
         res['Name']=data['Name']
         res['SNo']=data['SNo']
         res['Status']=data['Status']
         sample1['Details']=res
         #sample1['Details'].update(res)
```

But it's giving me the one result set only, all are overriding to that.

```
 'Details':{
        {
        'Name':'n3',
         'SNo':3,
         'Status':{
                   'state':'None',
                    'Health':'Ok'
                  }
        }           
            }
```

And also tried with using 'update()' but it throwing me key error 'Details'

```
          sample1['Details'].update(res)
```

Can anyone help me with that...

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `has_key` (Python 2 only) by `in` (works with Python 2 & 3). See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/.

Second, you overwrite the value mapped to `Details` for on each data having the correct keys: that's why you get only the last result. `Details` should be mapped to a list.

Third, you use the same (mutable) value `res` for each data having the correct keys: even if you use a list, you'll have `n` times the last value.

Replace your code by:

```
sample1={'Details': []} # an empty list
# don't create res here
for data in sample:
     if 'Name' in data and 'SNo' in data and 'Status' in data:
         res={} # but here: a new res per data
         res['Name']=data['Name']
         res['SNo']=data['SNo']
         res['Status']=data['Status']
         sample1['Details'].append(res) # append the current res
```

A more pythonic code would be:

```
required = set(['Name', 'SNo', 'Status'])
details = []
for data in sample:
    try:
        details.append({field: data[field] for field in required})
    except KeyError:
        pass

sample1 = {'Details': details}
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
required = set(['Name', 'SNo', 'Status'])
details = [{field: data[field] for field in required}
           for data in sample 
           if set(data) >= required]
sample1 = {'Details': details}
```